# CNCURSES addstring with string substitution of type \()

Tags: swift, linux, ncurses

I am following Dan Gookin's Guide to ncurses at the same time as I attempt to adapt the code into swift. First I noticed that `printw` is unavailable as C modules cannot import variadic functions, but this can be easily avoided using `addstr`.

Now the second problem, which leads to this question, is that I am not finding a way of passing the contents of a variable to `addstr` if the contents of the variable were created using `getstr`, so please consider the following:

```
import Foundation 
import CNCURSES // marathon: https://github.com/lf-araujo/Cncurses.git
import Glibc

initscr()

var first = [Int8]()
getstr(&first)

addstr("What is your last name? ")
refresh()

var last = [Int8]()
getstr(&last)

addstr("Pleased to meet you, \(first) \(last)!")
refresh()

getch()
endwin()
exit(0)
```

If I enter John Smith as my name, the result of the above is two empty brackets `[] []`.

- How do I pass the contents of `first` and `last` to `addstr` in this particular case?